# Add class to HTML attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to add the class `btn` to my hyperlink after the page loads.

Here is my current script:

**HTML**

```
<span id="callnow" class="mhMobile callnow"><a href="tel:01234567890">01234567890</a></span>
```

**JS**

```
(function(text){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector(".callnow a").addClass("btn");
    }, 1000);
})()
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/wnfmqsLf/

Comment: Many thanks - will look at this :-)

Comment: Using native api's `document.querySelector(".callnow a").classList.add("btn");` also as you have specified ID use `#callnow`

Comment: @Satpal Thankyou for this. That's handy to know in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".callnow a").addClass("btn");
```

should solve the problem

Comment: Fantastic! I have a working version here: https://jsfiddle.net/wnfmqsLf/2/ Thank you.

Comment: Super )))))))))

Comment: I will green tick in 10 minutes ;-)

Comment: should use inside `$(function(){ ... })` to make sure the script run after document loaded.